# Array value to string function

Tags: java, arrays, string, random, int

So basically I need to make a hash table, I understand how to do it with a string array but I need to do so with a random array I make.

Basically here is my random number code that another user gave me

```
    int[] array = new int[8000];
    Random rng = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 8000; i++) {
    array[i] = rng.nextInt(65536);  
    }
```

I need this to somehow turn into something like this in my professor's example code

```
String[] array = { "100", "510", "170", "214", "268", "398",
            "235", "802", "900", "723", "699", "1", "16", "999", "890",
            "725", "998", "978", "988", "990", "989", "984", "320", "321",
            "400", "415", "450", "50", "660", "624" };
```

Which i tried and did this:

```
 int[] array = new int[8000];
 Random rng = new Random();
 for (int i = 0; i < 8000; i++) {
     array[i] = rng.nextInt(65536);
     String strI = Integer.toString(i);
     String[] array = {i + "," };
```

}

Comment: I need to make it a string variable in order to pass it into my method I have created for hash table function that takes a String array and string array length

Comment: edit your original post.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a `String[]` and fill that (and I would prefer using the `array.length`, instead of hardcoding 8000 again). Something like,

```
String[] array = new String[8000];
Random rng = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     array[i] = String.valueOf(rng.nextInt(65536));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way of writing this is to use a stream.

```
Random rng = new Random();
String[] array = rng.ints(8000, 0, 65536).mapToObj(Integer::toString).toArray(String[]::new);
```

However streams were only introduced in Java 8.